# BeforeProperties and AfterProperties to check Folder name changed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, folder

What field do I need in an `ItemUpdating` event receiver to check whether a folder's name was changed?

I have tried:

```
        var before1 = properties.BeforeProperties["Name"];
        var after1 = properties.AfterProperties["Name"];
        var before2 = properties.BeforeProperties["Title"];
        var after2 = properties.AfterProperties["Title"];
        var before3 = properties.BeforeProperties["LinkFilename"];
        var after3 = properties.AfterProperties["LinkFilename"];
        var var1 = properties.ListItem["LinkFilename"];
```

They all return `null` apart from the last line, which returns the original folder name (not the new folder name).

Comment: did you check this http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122

Comment: AfterProperties requires Internal Name http://chuvash.eu/2011/09/09/afterproperties-kraver-internalname/

Comment: I'm aware that the column name must be the internal column name. My question is WHICH column name do I use to get the folder name? I thought it would be LinkFilename but I just get back null.

Comment: are you modifing the folder name or something?
because if you dont you dont need before or after properties just use properties.ListItem.Folder.Name

Comment: Marco - yes. Folder name is changed, `ItemUpdating` event receiver fires, but I can't get the before and after values for the folder name.

Comment: ItemUpdating is triggered when the process begin, I recomend you to process the changes on the ItemUpdated, there  you will find the after and before properties. The ItemUpdated is triggered once the change are already done.

Comment: I can't use `ItemUpdated` because there is no way for me to know what the original value for the folder name was! With ItemUpdated there is no value in `BeforeProperties`.

Comment: My real problem is what COLUMN NAME do I need to look at to get the folder name. If the folder was a file, like a Word file, what column name would I use to get the file's name? I thought 'LinkFilename', but apparently not...

Comment: Correction on my comment that there is no value in BeforeProperties when using ItemUpdated. There IS with a document library, not with a list. So I changed from using ItemUpdating to ItemUpdated and I still get nulls :(

Comment: I also tried getting the value of another column which I KNOW should work, "Author", and even for this I'm getting null. What am I doing wrong?